# MySQL Select within another select

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a query as follows

```
select
  Sum(If(departments.vat, If(weeklytransactions.weekendingdate Between
  '2011-01-04' And '2099-12-31', weeklytransactions.takings / 1.2,
  If(weeklytransactions.weekendingdate Between '2008-11-30' And '2010-01-01',
  weeklytransactions.takings / 1.15, weeklytransactions.takings / 1.175)),
  weeklytransactions.takings)) As Total,
  weeklytransactions.weekendingdate,......
```

and another that returns a vat rate as follows

```
select format(Max(Distinct vat_rates.Vat_Rate),3) From vat_rates Where
vat_rates.Vat_From <= '2011-01-03'
```

I want to replace the hard coded if statement with the lower query, replacing the date in the lower query with weeklytransactions.weekendingdate.

After Kevin's comments, here is the full query I'm trying to get to work;

```
Select Max(vat_rates.vat_rate) As r, 
If(departments.vat, weeklytransactions.takings / r, weeklytransactions.takings) As Total, 
weeklytransactions.weekendingdate, 
Week(weeklytransactions.weekendingdate), 
round(datediff(weekendingdate,     (if(month(weekendingdate)>5,concat(year(weekendingdate),'-06-01'),concat(year(weekendingdate)-1,'-06-01'))))/7,0)+1 as fyweek, 
cast((Case When Month(weeklytransactions.weekendingdate) >5 Then Concat(Year(weeklytransactions.weekendingdate), '-',Year(weeklytransactions.weekendingdate) + 1) Else Concat(Year(weeklytransactions.weekendingdate) - 1, '-',Year(weeklytransactions.weekendingdate)) End) as char) As fy,
business_units.business_unit 
From departments Inner Join (business_units Inner Join weeklytransactions On business_units.buID = weeklytransactions.businessUnit) On departments.deptid = weeklytransactions.departmentId 
Where (vat_rates.vat_from <= weeklytransactions.weekendingdate and business_units.Active = true and business_units.sales=1) 
Group By weeklytransactions.weekendingdate, business_units.business_unit Order By fy desc, business_unit, fyweek
```

Regards
Pete

Comment: So? what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I read your question correctly, your problem is about having the result of another `SELECT` used to be returned by the result of your main query (plus depending on how acquainted you are with SQL, maybe you haven't had the occasion to learn about `JOIN`s?).

You can have subqueries you extract data from within a `SELECT`, provided you define it within the `FROM`clause. The following query will work, for example:

```
SELECT A.a, B.b
FROM A
    JOIN (SELECT aggregate(c) FROM C) AS B
```

Notice that there is no reference to table A within the subquery. Thing is, you cannot just add it like that to the query, as the subquery doesn't know it is a subquery. So the following won't work:

```
SELECT A.a, B.b
FROM A
    JOIN (SELECT aggregate(c) FROM C WHERE C.someValue = A.someValue) AS B
```

Back to basics. What you want to do here visibly, is to aggregate some data associated to each of the records of another table. For that, you will need merge your `SELECT` queries and use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT A.a, aggregate(C.c)
FROM A, C
WHERE C.someValue = A.someValue
GROUP BY A.a
```

Back to your tables, the following should work:

```
SELECT w.weekendingdate, FORMAT(MAX(v.Vat_Rate, 3)
FROM weeklytransactions AS w, vat_rates AS v
WHERE v.Vat_From <= w.weekendingdate
GROUP BY w.weekendingdate
```

Feel free to add and remove fields and conditions as you see fit (I wouldn't be surprised that you'd also want to use a lower bound when filtering the records from vat_rates, since the way I have written it above, for a given weekendingdate, you get records from that week + the weeks before!).

---

So it looks like my first try did not address the actual problem. With the additional information provided in the comments, as well as the new complete query, let's see how this goes.

We are still missing error messages, but normally the query as written should result in MySQL having the following complaint:

```
ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'vat_rates' in field list
```

Why? Because the `vat_rates` table does not appear in the `FROM` clause, whereas it should. Let's make that more obvious by simplifying the query, removing all references to the `business_units` table as well as the fields, calculations and order that do not add or remove anything to the problem, leaving us with the following:

```
SELECT MAX(vat_rates.vat_rate) AS r, 
  IF(d.vat, w.takings / r, w.takings) AS Total
FROM departments AS d
  INNER JOIN weeklytransactions AS w ON w.departmentId = d.deptid
WHERE vat_rates.vat_from <= w.weekendingdate
GROUP BY w.weekendingdate
```

That cannot work, and will produce the error mentioned above. It looks like there is no `FOREIGN ID` between the `weeklytransactions` and `vat_rates` tables, so we have no choice but to do a `CROSS JOIN` for the moment, hoping that the condition in the `WHERE` clause and the aggregate function used to get `r` are enough to fit the business logic at hand here. The following query should return the expected data instead of an error message (I also remove `r` since that seems to be an intermediate value judging by the comments that were written):

```
SELECT IF(d.vat, w.takings / MAX(v.vat_rate), w.takings) AS Total
FROM vat_rates AS v, departments AS d
  INNER JOIN weeklytransactions AS w ON w.departmentId = d.deptid
WHERE v.vat_from <= w.weekendingdate
GROUP BY w.weekendingdate
```

From there, assuming it works, you will only need to put back all the parts I removed to get your final query. I am a tad doubtful about the way the VAT rate is gotten here, but I have no idea what your requirements are in that regard so I leave it up to you to make sure that works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I don't know how to do the calculation that was in the If statement as I don't know how to address the vat rate i.e. Select
  Max(vat_rates.vat_rate) As r,
  If(departments.vat, weeklytransactions.takings / r, weeklytransactions.takings) As Total,....  if I run it I cannot find r as it doesn't exist at this point

Comment: Could you please clarify that in your question above? Judging by your comment here, it looks like your problem is actually vastly different from the one I tried to answer. Make sure to provide de full queries (and not just what is between `SELECT` and `FROM`) that are of interest, to state what you are trying to achieve as clearly as possible and also explain what you've tried and the problems it still poses. Unless people make big assumptions the way I did, they are unlike to post answers since the actual question is not clear the way it is written.

Comment: Kevin, in my original select I was doing a calculation with hard coded values and wanted to replace it with a more dynamic approach by returning the vat_rate into the if statement (if possible).

Comment: Phew, what a query! Is that the original one you want to update, or a work-in-progress? You want to put the vat_rate value where exactly? The first `IF` statement I assume? In any case, the query you put in your question should be stripped down to the bare minimum, that is if the answer to my last question is 'yes' remove all references to the business_units table (that does not seem to add any meaningful information here), as well as the fields other than `r` and `Total`. Once we help you fix your problem using the simplified query, you should be able to apply the fix to the big one yourself.

Comment: Also, the way you explain your problem in your last comment makes me understand that you want to replace `r` with `MAX(vat_rates.vat_rate)` within the `IF`. But if you are asking for help in here, I assume this is not that simple... If you have an error message from MySQL, make sure to put it in your question as well. I'll take another look at your question and at your query around lunch time, later today, and am less likely to take a shot in the dark the clearer the question and its context.

Comment: Right, I have added a second part to my answer. Does that actually answer your problem, or have I missed the target again?